# Java Unparseable Date difference in formats

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

How to differentiate between data-entry being (a) invalid date or (b) invalid format?

I have the following code for handling date inputs from an text file.

```
    public boolean dateIsValid(String date) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");          
        formatter.setLenient(false);
            try {
                Date dateParsed = (Date) formatter.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;

        }
```

I have everything working as I want it to. The only problem I have is I am unable to differentiate the different parse exceptions thrown. For example:

if String date = 18/10/2012 --> `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "18/10/2012"` 

if String date = 2-12-2001  --> `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2-12-2001"`

As you can see, both the wrong formats throw the same error. How can I differentiate them so that I can handle them differently?

**EDIT**

To be more precise, in case of date 18/10/2012, I should throw an invalid date error and in the case of date 2-12-2001, I need to throw an invalid format exception. I dont need to handle different formats. I just need a way of getting different exceptions for these two different cases.

Comment: Seems like you have many patterns to receive the Date in string format. Try with the accepted ones for your system. For example, "18/10/2012" format is "dd/MM/yyyy" while "2-12-20012" may be "dd-MM-yyyy" or "MM-dd-yyyy".

Comment: I would have if it was left up to me. It is part of a much larger application where the strings are read out of a file and they are stored in mm/dd/yyyy format and I need to handle the bad formats and invalid dates separately.

Comment: Well, then these are invalid dates and you should handle them separately.

Comment: both fail for the same reason: the 2 first chars cannot represent a Month.

Comment: You're going to want to try a regex match to see if the string "can be parsed" (i.e., it has numbers and slashes in the correct places, and no characters, etc).  Then if it fails to match it's "not parseable".  After that you can attempt to DateFormat it.  If it fails at that time it will be because the date wasn't "valid"

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be at this line

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

For the first error it looks like that the date is coming first and the month later so it should be like

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Second error shows the incorrect format of the date supplied since it is containing `-` whereas you are expecting the format containing `/` ie like

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

If you want to handle different formats then try like this:

```
String[] formatDates= {"MM/DD/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy"};

Date tryParse(String dateString)
{
    for (String formatDate: formatDates)
    {
        try
        {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(formatDate).parse(dateString);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {}
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I know the source of the errors. I am testing the method under various circumstances of the string input and I need to handle them separately.

Comment: @Nikhil:- Updated the answer to handle multiple formats of dates.

Comment: Thanks for the code R.T, but you see, I dont need to handle other formats (I know its bad, but that the requirement of the project). So I just need to say whether its invalid date or invalid format. Doesnt you code throw the same exception for dates, say 42/32/2001 and 1?1?2011 though the former is completely invalid date and the later is just wrong format ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you write code to parse the date strings yourself, you will not know why the format threw the exception.

I recommend a variation of the R. T. answer above.
Specifically, instead of creating a new formatter every time, create four (in that example) formatters at startup (in the constructor or in a static block).

Comment: Is that the only way then? Writing my own parsing code? I checked for the list of methods of the exception. There is one getCause method, but `e.getCause` is showing NULL in both the cases. Anyways, thanks for the input.

Comment: cause will either be null or will contain a wrapped exception.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
public Date dateIfValid(String format, String date) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);          
    formatter.setLenient(false);
        try {
            return dateParsed = (Date) formatter.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
}

Date mmddyy = dateIfavlid("MM/dd/yy", date.replace("[^0-9]", "/"));
Date ddmmyy = dateIfavlid("dd/MM/yy", date.replace("[^0-9]", "/"));

if (mmddyy != null && ddmmyy == null) {
```

Note: this can be used to detect ambigous dates such as 01/02/03 which might be 3rd Feb 2001

Comment: Hey Peter, please see my comment under R.Ts solution. Thats the problem I am finding solution for. Thanks for the code though!